# How to read data from different paths at once on firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read data from separate paths at once, is it possible,
like if the user have list of uid of others can he read those at once, if not what is good practice? better to read all in loop?

Comment: If you have a list of paths, retrieving the items one at a time is quite fast. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786.

Comment: thnx! @FrankvanPuffelen you my HERO:)

Comment: I mostly have a few years of a head start on developers new to Firebase. :-)